# UWP: How to take photo with all metadata using MediaCapture?

Tags: uwp, camera, metadata, exif, mediacapture

now i take photo using MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync but i got no exif metadata in it. I try using SoftwareBitnmap class, but got only BitmapPropertySet with manufacturer and model data only.

I need all metadata that device can support, like making photo with windows 10 build in Camera app.

Answer (score 0):

To get the image-specific properties, you need to call [GetImagePropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh770646). The returned [ImageProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207718) object exposes members that contain basic image metadata fields.

If you want to access a larger set of file metadata, you need to use the [ImageProperties.RetrievePropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207732) method. Please see [Image Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/image-metadata)
 for more information.

The following is a simple code sample:

```cs
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

StorageFile imageFile = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (imageFile != null)
{
    ImageProperties props = await imageFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
    var requests = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
    requests.Add("System.Photo.EXIFVersion");
    IDictionary<string, object> retrievedProps = await props.RetrievePropertiesAsync(requests);
    if (retrievedProps.ContainsKey("System.Photo.EXIFVersion"))
    {
        var exifVersion = (string)retrievedProps["System.Photo.EXIFVersion"];
    }
}
```

Please note:

> For a complete list of Windows Properties, including the identifiers and type for each property, see [Windows Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd561977).
>
> Some properties are only supported for certain file containers and image codecs. For a listing of the image metadata supported for each image type, see [Photo Metadata Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ee872003).
>
> Because properties that are unsupported may return a null value when retrieved, always check for null before using a returned metadata value.